# Prove the following series converges uniformly.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the following series converge uniformly ?
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-2}}{k!(a+k)},~~ x, a>0.$$

Comment: Consider $\sum \frac{x^k}{k!} \frac{1}{x^2 (a+k)}$ and compare with the series expansion of exponential function

Comment: Yes, it does for $x\ge \delta>0$.  Use the [Weierstrass_M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).  The function does not exist for $x=0$.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. I take it that $a>0$ is a fixed constant, while $x>0$ is the variable, but you should make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the convergence is uniform on $(0,\infty).$ Let $S_n(x)$ be the $n$th partial sum. Then $S_n$ is uniformly Cauchy on $(0,\infty).$ That certainly implies $|S_n(x)-S_{n-1}(x)| < 1$ on $(0,\infty)$ for large $n.$ But $S_n(x)-S_{n-1}(x)= x^{n-2}/(n!(a+n)),$ which is unbounded on $(0,\infty)$ for $n>2.$ That's a contradiction, proving the convergence is not uniform.